# Create Onclick link to local html file

Tags: ggiraph

All examples of onclick in GGiraph seems to be linking some wikipedia page. For the description of the onclick function it says "Click actions must be a string column in the dataset containing valid javascript instructions".

Does this also mean that I can link to a local html file? If so, how would one do that

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
<button onclick="javascript:location.href='<filepath>/<filename>.html'">Submit</button>
```

This helped me navigate to another local html file.